# Having problems with verrifyin password with sha1 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, password-encryption

I am trying to use the sha1 to verify the password that is encrypted in the database using the same procedure. It does not give an error and it does not do anything as well. I presume I am doing something wrong which I do not know.

Model

```
function check_login ($email, $password) {
        $this->load->database();
        // Query to retrieve the user's details
        // based on the received username and password

        $sha_password = sha1($password);
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', $sha_password);
        $q = $this->db->get()->result();

        // The results of the query are stored in $q.
        // If a value exists, then the user account exists and is validated

        if (is_array($q) && count($q) == 1) {
            // Set the users details into the $details property of this class
            $this->details = $q[0];
            // Call set_session to set the user's session 
            $this->set_session();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Controller

```
public function login() {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            // return main page if submitted form is invalid.

            $this->load->view('abt_login');
        } else {
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $this->load->model('abt_db');
            $q = $this->abt_db->check_login($email, $password);
            if ($q) {
//                $this->abt_db->set_session($q);
                redirect('index.php/abovetheblues/abt_abovetheblues');
            } else {
                $this->show_login(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you encode your database ?
Have you tried to print these values ?

Comment: When you mean encode the database I do not know what you mean as I am still learning

Comment: Did you try trimming the password? Might be some white space issue

Comment: try by removing xss_clean validation for password.

Comment: I have done that but still does not do anything

Answer (score 0):

make some change in your function

```
    function check_login ($email, $password) {
    $this->load->database();
    $sha_password = sha1($password);
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $sha_password);
    $q = $this->db->get()->result();
    $num_rows=$q->num_rows();
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        $this->set_session();
        return true;
    }
    else
    return false;
}
```